# Website visits from US and Russia government/military domains?

Tags: google, google-analytics, google-search-console, analytics, visitors

I am using Google Analytics to track visits to my personal academic website, which only contains my CV and (non-sensitive) research work. Usually, all my visitors are from a university service provider.

Recently, I have been receiving **massive** amount of hits from the US and Russia. Strangely, none of them is from universities or research institutes. Instead, a lot of them are from military and government domains! Some example service providers include: `dod network information center`, `headquarters usaisc`, `mia adsl eeua`, `navy network information center (nnic)`, `mil`, etc.

As I said, all the contents on my personal website are harmless and personal. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question kinda brings up a weird point that people are not aware of.

Some HR ATS software will scour the Internet for CV's and categorize them. These links can be shared through databases. Every time a CV search is conducted within the ATS software, it is possible that the HR will check the web page for updates. Some ATS cache for a period, some ping the page every time. Much of this depends on the user. It does not always have to be a CV. HR professionals can mark other resources of interest depending upon the software.

I have found that when a CV is online, periodic heavy traffic can come from identifiable site/network patterns. It can be government contractors, it can be DoD, it can be research companies, it can be sleazy contracting companies, it can be universities, etc. It is not uncommon. Especially these days when the U.S. Government has an increased interest in hiring for various projects related to Internet security and intelligence related work.

I used to maintain a CV online as well as having used these ATS software before and coding for ATS software companies. Much of the traffic is due to HR professionals not being terribly tech savvy and making broad searches and/or settings. It is possible that a CV will see a lot of traffic, however, only occasionally bubble to the top of the list where you might get a call. This is due to usage. It is also possible that you will get several calls a week.

It is good that a CV is getting pings if you are looking for work. You may want to pay attention to this and update the online CV specifically to perform well in an ATS. My ATS resume advice is rather old so I will not share it. However, CVs that perform well in ATS do not match the common advice for CVs that will be read by a human. You may want to do a search for current advice.

Answer (score 1):

If that's your academic website and you are running it through university (which is state founded) you'll get your answer. It's not a strange behavior, it happens in US all the time. There are numerous organisations that are doing this so called "surveillance" jobs, mostly throughout bots and crawlers and they're reporting some patterns throughout programmed or preconfigured keywords. So, just don't worry about it.

But hey, maybe they're searching for you so they can give you a job. :)